# How to change the date display format for date elements in Notion API from relative to absolute?

Tags: notion-api, notion

I am currently working with the Notion API and I would like to modify the date display format of date elements within a Notion page from relative to absolute through a script. I know that this can be done manually, but my goal is to automate this process for all instances of date elements that are set by default to relative date display.

Is there a way to achieve this using the Notion API? I have looked through the Notion API documentation and I have not found any information on this specific task. I would appreciate any help or guidance on how to approach this problem. Thank you in advance!

I attempted to automate changing the date format display for date elements within a Notion page using the Notion API. First, I connected to the API and retrieved the page information. Then, I identified the date elements on the page. However, I am currently stuck on how to modify the display format property of the date element, which I believe is responsible for displaying a date in relative or absolute format.